# Basic trigger in PL/pgSQL, to flip a boolean field if another field has text

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I want a BOOLEAN field to be set to TRUE when a sibling TEXT field is set to a non-empty string. Vice versa, the BOOLEAN is set to FALSE when TEXT field is set to empty string.

The following function is running, but fails to flip the BOOLEAN field.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_flags_on_recipe_trigger_function_()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$BODY$

DECLARE

BEGIN

    IF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'recipe_') THEN

        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') OR (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            BEGIN
                NEW.is_baked_ = ( length( NEW.baking_instructions_ ) > 0 );
                NEW.is_roasted_ = ( length( NEW.roasting_instructions_ ) > 0 );
            END;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;

    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'This trigger is being used on the wrong table.';

    END IF;

     /* Should never reach this point. Branching in code above should always reach a call to RETURN. */
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpectedly reached the bottom of this function without calling RETURN.';

END;

$BODY$;
```

---

Is this kind of question about programming PL/pgSQL appropriate to this site? Or should I be posting this to StackOverflow?

Comment: Minor tweak: That inner `BEGIN END;` is unnecessary.

Comment: Totally appropriate unless it's *too* basic. But add the `[postgresql]` tag for `[plpgsql]` questions. Most regulars only have the major tags on their radar. I, for one, missed the question ...

Comment: As to the question: Your description contradicts the code example. You speak of *one* flag to be switched back and forth, you demonstrate *two* flags switched in one direction only. Which is it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter (a) Regarding one vs two flags, does it matter? I assume that once we arrive at the inside if the conditional testing code such as `IF (TG_TABLE_NAME…` we should put all the similar field-mutating code together. In this example that is a pair of Boolean fields. Is this approach wrong or ill-advised in trigger code? I am new to triggers. (b) I don't know what you mean by "one direction only". My logic using `>` should flip the Boolean `TRUE` *and* `FALSE`

Comment: (a) Doesn't matter much for the core of the question. But if I read a question and the description contradicts the example, uncertainty grows whether this is going to become confusing / frustrating and I tend to pass on the question. If I kept reading, because I recognized your name. (b) You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger function can be improved:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insup_bef_recipe()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'recipe_' THEN
   IF TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
      NEW.is_baked_   := NEW.baking_instructions_ <> '';
      NEW.is_roasted_ := NEW.roasting_instructions_ <> '';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'This trigger is being used on the wrong table.';
END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- Do not use a [separate code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html) without need. Removed the spurious `BEGIN .. END`.
- `NEW.baking_instructions_ <> ''` is a 100% identical drop-in replacement for
  `length( NEW.baking_instructions_ ) > 0`. Just shorter and faster.
- [The plpgsql assignment operator is `:=`, not `=`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace)
- Removed multiple parentheses to demonstrate they are just noise.

### Simplify

Given the trigger definition in your answer (which should be in your question), you can further simplify the trigger function.

- If your trigger function is not intended to be generic but for a certain trigger on a certain table (which is the normal case) I suggest to reflect that in the function name instead of adding code and error messages to the function body. Much cheaper and cleaner (IMHO), but that's a matter of taste and style:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insup_bef_recipe()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
NEW.is_baked_   := NEW.baking_instructions_ <> '';
NEW.is_roasted_ := NEW.roasting_instructions_ <> '';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And since this trigger only has work to do when any of the involved columns have been changed, you only need to trigger it in those cases:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef_recipe
BEFORE INSERT
OR UPDATE OF is_baked_, baking_instructions_, is_roasted_, roasting_instructions_
ON recipe_
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insup_bef_recipe();
```

### Simplify further

Do you really *need* those flags materialized as additional columns? Could be completely (and more reliably) replaced with simple expressions in your queries:

```
baking_instructions_ <> '' AS is_baked_
```

Then you don't need a trigger at all. You could create a view with that expression. Or even "generated field". Detailed instructions:
[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)
[Computed / calculated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Comment: Amazing answer. That should provide an excellent lesson for trigger newbies.

Comment: As for needing an extra Boolean column in this scenario, you are correct in that I do *not* need one in theory. I am deliberately de-normalizing because of performance. I should have said so in question. I am collecting scientific readings every minute, stored in `TEXT` columns. That's a half million records a year, 30k each field. I need to find the few missing values caused by instrument data-collection glitches. I'm trying to avoid sequential reads of tens of gigs of data that would otherwise rarely be read.

Comment: @BasilBourque: For the `few missing values` you might be interested in functional partial indexes instead of redundant flags. [Several related answer can be found here.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=[postgresql]+partial+index+on+an+expression) Ask a new question if those do not clarify the potential ...

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

The problem was not inside this function.

The problem was the trigger being defined with an `AFTER` rather than `BEFORE`.

I had this…

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER set_flags_on_recipe_trigger_
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON recipe_
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_flags_on_recipe_trigger__function_();
```

rather than…

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER set_flags_on_recipe_trigger_
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON recipe_
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_flags_on_recipe_trigger__function_();
```

## Lesson Learned

If the function seems to be running correctly, confirmed by use of `RAISE NOTICE`, but the row remains unaffected, check the `AFTER` versus `BEFORE`.